# When trying to save and commit a new parent object that has relation (child), how can I avoid saving duplicate children?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So, I basically I have an app using Flask-SQLAlchemy. It's a trivia database, and I have 3 tables (that are relevant here). `trivia` for the questions, `users` for users who can post new questions and `categories`. So trivia  has one column `author_id` pointing to the `users` table (sry, confusing that I use author and user like that), and `category_id` to a category.

Relevant tables + marshmallow schemata:

```
class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'trivia_categories'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    category = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    questions = db.relationship('Trivia', backref='category', single_parent=True)

class CategorySchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        sqla_session = db.session

    questions = fields.List(fields.Nested("TriviaSchemaCondensed", exclude=('category',)), many=True)

class Trivia(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'trivia_questions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('trivia_users.id'), nullable=True)
    validated = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('trivia_categories.id'))
    difficulty = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    type = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    question = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    correct_answer = db.Column(db.String(75), nullable=False)
    incorrect_answers = db.relationship(
        'IncorrectAnswer',
        backref='related_question',
        cascade='all, delete, delete-orphan',
        single_parent=True,
    )

class TriviaSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Trivia
        sqla_session = db.session

    category = fields.Nested("CategorySchema", exclude=('questions',), many=False)
    author = fields.Pluck("UserSchema", 'nickname')
    incorrect_answers = fields.List(fields.Nested("IncorrectAnswerSchema", exclude=("related_question",)))
```

Note the relevant `relationship` in `Category` pointing to `Trivia`, and that `Trivia` has a field `category_id`.

When a new question is inserted, I add the `user` object to the `trivia` object. Then I check if the desired category already exists (categories basically only has an `id` column as primary key and a `category` column which has a unique constraint). I do this by  querying the db. If I get a result back, I simply attach this to the new `trivia` question, otherwise I first create and commit the new `category` to the db, and then attach it to the question.

Finally I commit the question. Relevant part of controller:

```
def create(user, body):
    """
    This function creates a new trivia question in the trivia structure
    based on the passed in trivia data
    :param trivia:  trivia question to create in trivia structure
    :return:        201 on success
    """

    trivia = body

    retrieved_user = User.query.filter_by(id=user).first()

    # Create a new trivia instance using the schema and the passed in trivia
    trivia_schema = TriviaSchema()
    incorrect_answer_schema = IncorrectAnswerSchema()

    # Save category for manipulations down the road
    raw_category = trivia.get("category")

    transform_incorrect_a = lambda raw_answer: { "answer": raw_answer }
    trivia["incorrect_answers"] = map(transform_incorrect_a, trivia.get("incorrect_answers"))
    trivia["category"] = { "category": raw_category }
    trivia["validated"] = True

    new_trivia = trivia_schema.load(trivia, session=db.session)

    new_trivia.author = retrieved_user

    # Check if category already exists
    category = (
      Category.query.filter(Category.category == raw_category)
      .one_or_none()
    )

    if category is None:
        category = Category(category=raw_category)
        db.session.add(category)


    new_trivia.category = category


    # Add the trivia question to the database
    db.session.add(new_trivia)
    db.session.commit()

    # Serialize and return the newly created trivia question in the response
    data = trivia_schema.dump(new_trivia)

    return data, 201
```

My problem: the saving always fails if the category already exists. I get an IntegrityError because the uniqueness constraint is violated:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely)
(MySQLdb._exceptions.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry 'stringg' for key 'category'")
[SQL: INSERT INTO trivia_categories (category) VALUES (%s)]
```

However, it should not create a new category entry in the first place (given that I already pull the existing one if it's the case)! It's as if SQLAlchemy always wants to create a new category entry no matter if it already exists and regardless of whether I have already queried the db for this.

Interestingly, with the author (user) everything is fine - it's not trying to create new users!

I'll be super grateful if anyone has any ideas or insights. I've been googling like a madman and I can't find a solution.

Thank you very much!